# How to extract all road data information (maxspeed, road width, nr. of lanes etc...) from HERE API based on coordinates?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I would like to get as much information as possible about road info by giving the coordinates.
So far I use this API url: https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json with a POST request like this:

```
  url = 'https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json'

params = {
"waypoint0":"47.2628,3.73926", 
"waypoint1":"47.26274,3.73919",
"attributes":"LINK_FCn(*)",

"apiKey":key,
}

resp = requests.post(url=url, params=params)
#__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
os.chdir(dir_write_unkown_roads)

try:
    data = resp.json() 
    json_object = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    with open("road_data.json", "w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
        
except ValueError as e:
    json_object = ""

print('printing code respones',str(resp.status_code))
```

I have this problem: This API uses the above points to first calculate a set of coordinate points (routing) between waypoint0 and waypoint1 and returns road attributes based on the calculated points by the API.
I would like to know if there is a way to get road attributes of the road where a SINGLE point belongs to. Like reverse geocode API but in return get the road attributes of the segment the point belongs to. Is there this option in HERE?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of our HERE map attribute apis. The HERE Map Attributes API REST API offers simple and fast access to the rich HERE Map Content, seamlessly extensible by your own map data.

Please check the below document for more details.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/index.html

And you can make use of below example to fetch the attributes based on LATITUDE,LONGITUDE.

https://demo.support.here.com/examples/v3/pde_get_any_link_info